# Accessing queue before thread completes in Python and Tkinter

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, queue

I am using Tkinter to build a GUI for an agent based model. The model runs on a 'yearly' time step. I am trying to get model.py to communicate to the GUI each timestep (i.e., each 'year') using threading.

Currently model.py iterates through each 'year' as follows:

```
def run_model(self, step_count, thread_queue = None): 
    for i in range(step_count):
       self.thread_queue.put(self.time)
       self.step()
```

In the above function, step_count simply tells the model how many 'years' it should run, and the self.step function runs the model for one 'year'.

In gui.py, I currently do the following:

```
def run_model(self):
    data = [
        {'b_min_t': self.b_min_t.get()},
        {'b_max_t': self.b_max_t.get()},
        {'sc_min_t': self.sc_min_t.get()},
        {'sc_max_t': self.sc_max_t.get()},
    ]

    self.mylabel.config(text='Running Model')
    # set time to run model
    model_run_years = 5

    # run model, collect outputs and save dataframe
    self.run_model_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.model.run_model(model_run_years, self.thread_queue), daemon=True)
    self.run_model_thread.start()
    self.after(1000, self.listen_for_result)

def listen_for_result(self):
    '''
    Check if there is something in the queue
    '''
    try:
        self.res = self.model.thread_queue.get()
        self.mylabel.config(text=self.res)
    except queue.Empty:
        self.after(1000, self.listen_for_result)
```

This current implementation clearly doesn't work as `self.mylabel.config` doesn't update until the model has run for the amount of time specified in `model_run_years`. Can anyone point me in the direction of the best way to achieve what I'm after? Essentially I want the GUI to update `self.mylabel.config` after each `self.step()` - I am running graphics in the background that I eventually want to display in the GUI, that require updates each 'year'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward in the end. Just a case of running the step function from inside the GUI in a thread.